# Safari returning whitespace on AJAX response

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am now onto the next page of my project for a volunteer management system and am trying an Ajax response for positioning the volunteers. The web page loads all the positions from the database, then next to each position it loads all the volunteers into a select box. Once a volunteer is selected it sends this via Ajax. In firefox this works fine, in Safari the data sends and receives okay, but every time a change is made it adds a new line so the table goes further and further down the page. I cannot work out why it is doing this.

`echo "Updated $column_name to $text";`

This is the PHP return, this comes back fine.

The Ajax code is:

```
                    <div id="msg"></div>
                  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="error" style="display: none;">...</div>
                <span id="result"></span>
<table align="center" class="adminMarshalPositions">
<tr>
<td class='adminEmail' width="5%" align="center"><b>No</b></td>
<td class='adminEmail' width="15%" align="center"><b>Name</b></td>
<td class='adminEmail' width="15%" align="center"><b>Person 1</b></td>
<td class='adminEmail' width="5%" align="center"><b>Qty</b></td>
<td class='adminEmail' width="15%" align="center"><b>Person 2</b></td>
</tr>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post"> 
<?php
**PHP SELECT STATEMENTS REMOVED**

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='adminEmail'>$positionNo</td>";
    echo "<td class='adminEmail'>$name</td>";

    echo "<td class='adminEmail' align='center'>";
        echo "<select name='person-1' class='marshal-select'>";
    if($person1 == '0') {
        echo "<option value='0'>Select Marshal</option>";
    }
    if($person1 != '0') {
        if($organisation == '') {
        echo "<option value='$person1'>$person1FirstName $person1LastName</option>";
        } else {
        echo "<option value='$person1'>$person1FirstName $person1LastName ($organisation)</option>";    
        }
        echo "<option value='0'>Select Marshal</option>";
    }
    $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM marshalTable ORDER BY lastName ASC, firstName ASC";  
    $result3 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql3);
    while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){
    $newPerson1Id = $row3["id"];
    $newPerson1FirstName = $row3["firstName"];
    $newPerson1LastName = $row3["lastName"];
    $organisation2 = $row3["organisation"];
    $avaliable = $row3["avaliable"];    
    if ($avaliable == '1') {
    if($organisation2 == '') {
        echo "<option value='$newPerson1Id'>$newPerson1FirstName $newPerson1LastName</option>";
    } else {
        echo "<option value='$newPerson1Id'>$newPerson1FirstName $newPerson1LastName ($organisation2)</option>";    
    } }
   }
    echo "</select>";
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td class='adminEmail' align='center'>";
        echo "<select name='qty' class='marshal-select'>";
    if($qty != '0') {
        echo "<option value='$qty'>$qty</option>";
    }
        echo "<option value='0'>0</option>";
        echo "<option value='1'>1</option>";
        echo "<option value='2'>2</option>";
        echo "<option value='3'>3</option>";
        echo "<option value='4'>4</option>";
        echo "<option value='5'>5</option>";
        echo "<option value='6'>6</option>";
        echo "<option value='7'>7</option>";
        echo "<option value='8'>8</option>";
        echo "<option value='9'>9</option>";
        echo "<option value='10'>10</option>";  
    echo "</select>";
    echo "</td>";


    echo "<td class='adminEmail' align='center'>";
        echo "<select name='person-2' class='marshal-select'>";
    if($person2 == '0') {
        echo "<option value='0'>Select Marshal</option>";
    }
    if($person2 != '0') {
        echo "<option value='$person2'>$person2FirstName $person2LastName</option>";
        echo "<option value='0'>Select Marshal</option>";
    }
    $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM marshalTable ORDER BY lastName ASC, firstName ASC";  
    $result3 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql3);
    while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){
    $newPerson2Id = $row3["id"];
    $newPerson2FirstName = $row3["firstName"];
    $newPerson2LastName = $row3["lastName"];
    $avaliable = $row3["avaliable"];    
    if($avaliable == '1') {
        echo "<option value='$newPerson2Id'>$newPerson2FirstName $newPerson2LastName</option>";
    }}
    echo "</select>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='positionNo' name='positionNo' value='$positionNo' class='positionNo'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='userID' name='userID' value='$userID' class='userID'>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</form>
</table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select.marshal-select').change(function() {
    let $select = $(this);

    var positionNo = $(this).parent().parent().find('td').find('.positionNo').val();
    var userID  = $('#userID').val();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'lib/positionMarshalProcess.php',
      data: {
        selectFieldValue: $select.val(),
        changeCol: $select.prop('name'),
        positionId: positionNo,
        userID: userID
      },
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data) {
                //alert(data);
                $.trim('#result');
                $('#result').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>"+data+"</div>");
            }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you try `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ""` just before you call `html()` in your client-side, is that helping?

Comment: Where exactly would this go sorry?

Comment: `$.trim('#result');` - this does absolutely not do, what you probably thought it does. (This will no empty any element, it trims whitespace from the start and the end of the _string value_ `#result` - which doesn't have any such whitespace, so the result of this whole statement is still the _text_ `#result`. You are not working on any HTML elements at all here, all you are doing is an operation on a text string.)

Comment: thank you, I have narrowed the problem to something in my css file, https://volunteershub.co.uk/vmsmain/assets/layout.css